# Error throwing when connecting api with client I'd and key

Tags: excel, vba, api, authentication, get

I'm trying to access data through an API that takes in a X-client-id and x-api-key. I've tried the following so far but it's not working. Can anyone help?

```
Dim request as new winhttprequest

Request.open "Get", url, False

Request.setrequestheader "Accept", "application/json"

Request.setrequestheader "X-client-id", "[Id]" 

Request.setrequestheader "x-api-key", "[key]"
```

Comment: Hi Kartik, Can you write a bit more about why it's not working? Do you get an error from the API? Is an error thrown in your code? If it's an API error response, what does the response contain? Etc. Have you checked with curl or Postman if your client-id and api-key are correct and work outside of your code?

Comment: Hi Michal, yes  I have. The api and the I'd and key works outside the code. I found out that I may have to encode this "[X-client-id]:[key]" together as 64 bytes which I have. I did the same for key but still getting the same error. Not sure how to send the encoded value along with the get request. The error I am getting is the user is not authorised to perform execute api invoke on resource.What I tried was to request.setrequestheader "Authorization", "Basic" & encoded value

Comment: If you managed to call the API from Postman, then you should do exactly the same things in your code that you did in postman. If you're encoding the values there then you should encode them here. Maybe there is a documentation that you could follow to correctly configure the connection?

Comment: Hi Michal, thanks again. So I'm not encoding the values on postman, guess I don't need to on vba as well then. Do u think the format of headers is correct?